# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHyperlinkRun

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, ms-word, xwpf, xdocreport

I am trying to:

1. Use a word document with "MergeFields" to fill it with data
2. Convert to a PDF document, using java

I have had this working before, and now all of a sudden i get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHyperlinkRun.

This occurs when i put the .war file on an Amazon EC2 server.
(all other libraries work fine)

Here are the libraries that i use:

> fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.odt.odfdom (v 1.0.4)
>
> fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.freemarker (v 1.0.4)
>
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core (1.0.5)
>
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf (1.0.5)
>
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml (1.0.5)
>
> org.apache.poi (3.11)

Is there anything wrong with my libraries? or is this just a server deployment issue?

Very thankful for help.

Below is my code:

```
 public byte[] wordToPdf(RequestHelper reqHelper, Map<String, Object> values, String docPath) throws IOException, XDocReportException, ServiceUnavailableException, E24Exception {
        try {
            ServletContext ctx = reqHelper.getRequest().getServletContext();
            InputStream tpl = new BufferedInputStream(ctx.getResourceAsStream(docPath));
            IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(tpl, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
            Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(ConverterTypeVia.XWPF);
            ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            report.convert(report.createContext(values), options, pdfOut);
            byte[] pdfImage = pdfOut.toByteArray();
            return pdfImage;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally got to a solution that worked for me, since this post has alot of views and no answers, i'll answer it myself for those who are in need!

I changed the version of all libraries that has anything to do with
 "apache.poi" to version 1.0.4

After that i used org.apache.poi version 3.9 instead of 3.11

So finally, to wrap it up... this is what i used in the end

> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core (1.0.4)
>
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf (1.0.4)
>
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml (1.0.4)
>
> org.apache.poi (3.9)

/Marcus